# options.UseSqlServer returns Error in startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a test Project using asp.net core.
For Connecting to database I'm using Entity framework.
I add appsetings.json file to the project and change the connection string as follows:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\mihanrayan;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;User = sa; Password = 123456"
  }
}
```

sql version is : mssql 2008 r2

in startup.cs class I add codes below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();

        }
```

but

```
options.UseSqlServer(
               Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
```

returns this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in
>   user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: Why would you think that `Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString` would resolve to that location within the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

`Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"])` is returning null.

`"Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionString"`

should probably be

`"ConnectionStrings:Defaultconnection"`

Answer (score 1):

It should be like as shown below:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this nuGet package:
**"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"**

Upon spending hours searching for the fix, this was what worked for me.

**NB: select the same version as your .net version**